# FirstOrDefault throwing exception instead of null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm trying using `FirstOrDefault` to get an item from my store. If it doesn't exist, I want it to return `null`.

I understand `FirstOrDefault` should do this. The database doesn't exist, so I expect it to return `null`, except it causes an `SQLException`.

Why isn't this just returning `null`?

```
var setting = context.Settings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ApplicationName == _applicationName && s.Name == name);
```

Comment: What do you mean the database doesn't exist?  What is the full text of the exception that's being thrown?  If the underlying table doesn't exist, then of course it's going to throw an exception, as it can't initially query for the records you're looking for!

Comment: what is the exception? you mentioned database does not exist so this is the exception, FirstOrDefault works if database exist

Comment: Post the exceptions full message because as mentioned it's probably thrown due to `context.Settings` and `FirstOrDefault` never even gets invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behavior, .FirstOrDefault() throws an exception when the source does not exist. Null is returned when the source does, but the specific entity does not exist.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: True, however if that really was the only problem, the exception that would be thrown would be an ArgumentNullException.

Comment: Good point. Your answer is more accurate for this situation. But it's remarkable how many people think .xOrDefault will return null in all situations.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The fact that a `SQLException` is thrown tells your that there was a problem even asking the database about the data you want to work on. As you say your "database doesn't exist" I would assume that the `SQLException` will be caused by that.

`FirstOrDefault` is most likely not even executed, as accessing the `Settings` property will already throw the `SQLException`.